# Finding Value in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to find if an object contains a certain value and then have that dictate the next steps of the operation. This is an object that is returned from Google Maps API. This is an exact example returned back from their API.

**Array**

```
[{'long_name': 'United States', 'short_name': 'US'}, {'long_name': 'California', 'short_name': 'CA'}];
```

**Conditional/Check**

```
if( $.inArray('US', array) == -1 ){

    alert('Your country is not supported.');

} else {
     alert('Your country is supported.');   
}
```

This doesn't work because it only looks at the index, and not values I believe. What's the cleanest and fastest way to find and return if the value exists in the array?

Comment: `array` is an object, not an array.

Comment: @FelixKling and js arrays are objects!

Comment: Yes, when I do $.type(array) it returns array.

Comment: But it's not an array, it's an object

Comment: @zerkms But not all objects are arrays, how is this a difficult concept?

Comment: Actually, it's not even an object, it's a syntax error

Comment: @Miura-shi: No it does not: http://jsfiddle.net/d5qv69je/. Or you haven't posted the data you actually have.

Comment: @adeneo: But that's likely just a typo.

Comment: The keys in your object must be unique ... did you mean to have an array with two objects in it?

Comment: My apologizes. I've fixed the typo as I added additional data to the array during the writing of the question,

Comment: @FelixKling - probably? Anyway, `$.inArray` obviously is for arrays, not objects, that would be just `"key" in object`

Comment: @Ja͢ck This is an object/array that is returned from Google Maps API for address_components

Comment: @Miura-shi it's not "an object/array" it's an object.

Comment: Again, please update your question with what you really have... it's obviously not an array. If `$.type` returns `array` for you, then you have something different than what you posted here.

Comment: This isn't a valid object. You can't have two keys with the same name in the same object. Are these supposed to be separate objects?

Comment: @Interrobang does the standard prevent you from having duplicate keys?

Comment: it is a hash array, inArray obviously only works with normal arrays

Comment: @JoshuaByer: Please don't call an object "hash array", it just adds to the confusion. JS has objects and arrays are a special kind of object.

Comment: @zerkms it won't throw an error, but the second use of the key will silently overwrite the first. Keys have to be unique, period.

Comment: @Interrobang well, they don't "have to be", strictly speaking it's a syntactically valid expression. I wouldn't say "invalid" to not confuse anyone (since that's not true)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find a match you could use [`jQuery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
var res = $.grep(arr, function(item) {
    return item.short_name == 'US';
});
```

It returns an array, which will be empty if there are no matches found.

Alternatively, you could use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var res = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.short_name == 'US';
});
```

#### Bonus

You can generalise it further:

```
function searchFunction(field)
{
    return function(arr, term) {
        return arr.filter(function(item) {
            return item[field] == term;
        };
    };
}

var searchByShortName = searchFunction('short_name');

if (searchByShortName(arr, 'US').length) {
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Very elegant. I appreciate your time on this very educational answer. I was a little unclear in my question and I do apologize. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something like this

```
var countries = [{'long_name': 'United States', 'short_name': 'US'},
{ 'long_name': 'California', 'short_name': 'CA'}]; //now this is an array with objects

function hasCountry(shortName){
    for(var i = 0, len = countries.length; i < len; i++){
        if(countries[i]['short_name'] === shortName) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if(hasCountry('US')){
   // not supported..
} else {
   // not supported
}
```

However, a better solution would be normalize the countries to an object like this.

```
var countries = {'US': 'United States', 'CA': 'California'}; // this is an object

if(countries['US'] != null){
    // supported
} else {
  // not supported
}
```

Comment: 1. syntax error (see syntax highlights) 2. It would be much better if `hasCountry` accepted both an array and a search term.